# SSRS - Add a page break after a specific group - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to add a page break after nth group?

I have a table that has two columns and is grouped by states.

```
State |  Name 

MA       Sarah 
         Bob
NY       Jane
TX       Klein
```

I want the 3rd group (TX), to be on it's own page. How do I add a page break after a specific group?

Comment: What version of SSRS is this? Also, is it specifically Texas, or the 3rd group regardless of State?

Comment: @IanPreston Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 10.50.2500.0. It's specifically TX. Though,there are only three groups, so it could just be the third group regardless of state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using 2008R2, you can set up page breaks in a Tablix to be conditionally enabled/disabled based on an expression - in your case you'd only be enabling it where the **State** is *TX*. Here's an example based on your sample Dataset:

[image]

I've just created a simple table based on this:

[image]

Note that I've added a Report Header to display a page number. Looks as you'd expect without any page breaks applied:

[image]

Now, if you select the State group in the Designer and look at the properties, you'll note there is a Page Break section:

[image]

I've set the **Disabled** property to be:

```
=IIf(Fields!State.Value = "TX", False, True)
```

i.e. only apply the Page Break for the *TX* group.

Now we get one Page Break in the report as required:

[image]

[image]

Comment: No problem at all, glad it helped!