# SSRS dynamic parameters passed through page header

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, erp

I am using SSRS to compile reports for an ERP implementation project. I am looking to display the unique job number onto the header of every sheet. So for example, on the order number 66, I should have 19 unique job numbers at the top of the 19 page headers. The format the job numbers are in are as follows:

```
66-1500001, 66-1500002 --> 66-1500019
```

I have a dataset named **JobNumber** and a field within this dataset named **JobProd_JobNum** . I need to do this without using a tablix, as these cannot be entered into the job header section of SSRS reports, so I have created a parameter called **JobParameter**. I have then used the following code within a stored procedure on a textbox I have placed on the header section:

```
=Parameters!JobParameter.Value
```

but this displays only the first job number, on all 19 pages:

```
661500001
```

I have tried using the join function, but this just joined all 19 job numbers onto each page together, where I need one unique job number to be displayed on each page

Is there anyway to write a loop within the stored procedure that will give the first page number the first job number, and so on until the 19th job number, to leave it something like this:

```
 page1, job number : 66-1500001 
 page2, job number : 66-1500002
 page3, job number : 66-1500003
 ...
 page19, job number : 66-1500019
```

Appreciate any help, Paul.

Comment: There is a good example of using page breaking by groups on the tablix here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435830/ssrs-add-a-page-break-after-a-specific-group-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: This is useful, but unfortunately it's not applicable here, as the data I am displaying in the header is coming from the dataset named above, so a tablix cannot be used. I don't have a problem with the paging of my data, as I am splitting it on each new instance of a group, which i have in the tablix contained in the body section, detailing order details, order qty, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been experimenting myself here an have found the answer. It is actually pretty simple. I have my tablix data which contains (dataset name in brackets)

```
1.Order Number (Orderhed_OrderNum) 
2.Job Number (JobProd_JobNum)
3.Sheet colour(OrderDtl_OrderQty)
4.SKU(OrderDtl_XPartNum)
4.Qty(OrderDtl_LineDesc)
```

The numbers are the order in which I have grouped my data, so 2 is a child of 1, 3 is a child of 2 etc. Within the tablix, I have the job number information, so all I need to do is to call the textbox it is using from the tablix, onto the page header. The textbox name was **JobProd_JobNum** so I create a textbox in the header section and attach the following expression:

```
=ReportItems!JobProd_JobNum.value
```

Which displays the 19 unique job numbers at the top of each relevant page in a Header format.